# How to use Azure App Settings in a Blazor WebAssembly Client side application at runtime as appsettings.json configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

[image]

- I'm Working on Blazor WebAssembly Client/Server project (directory structure as above)
- Have some application settings in both client and server projects.
- The projects are hosted in Azure.

**The problem** is in the *Client side* with the `appsettings.json`

- In the client side, the `appsettings.json` is within the `wwwroot` directory. It is okay to access the file within the app, However, ***the settings cannot be overwritten by Azure Portal Application Settings of the App service.***

It means, that after the app is deployed in Azure portal on a Web App Service, my configuration settings do not work with the application settings' variables.

This is the code in the `Progam.cs`, which works fine and read the configuration from the file, but ignores the configuration settings of the Web App Service on Azure.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
    //Add a named httpClient and set base Address and Default Request Headers
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("SOME_WEB_URL", client =>  // SOME_WEB_URL is defined in the appsettings.json or in the Azure App Service configuration (Application Settings)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["sbformsapi"]);
    });

    //Add a named httpClient and set base Address and Default Request Headers
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WEB_APP_API", client =>   // WEB_APP_API is defined in the 
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["sbwebappapi"]);
    });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    ....
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Could someone please guide how can I either

- set the appsettings.json file outside the wwwroot and read it from there?
  OR
- inject/use the values from Azure App Service configuration's Application settings at runtime?

I am talking about the application settings here (as in the pic)...

[image]

Comment: If there's any secrets in there, you might implement an API that returns configuration items that are specific for the front end. Have a look over here: [ASP.NET Core Blazor configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @wafers have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm trying to figure this out myself. Everyone seems to assume you can get the settings from an API, but what if the setting you need is the API url??

Answer (score 0):

Currently application settings are only available for the backend API associated with your Blazor App (assuming using Static App?).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/application-settings

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at the Blazor docs, I don't think it is possible to load Azure App Settings directly in a WebAssembly. You can look for yourself

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I suggest instead to put the backend URL in the appsettings.json and then use a backend service to load the configuration information from there.